# Find the conditional probability of a probability density function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose a random variable X has a probability density function 
$f(x)$ = $kx(1-x)$ for  $0\le x\le1$ and 0 otherwise.

Find P($X \le 0.4$ | $X \le 0.8$)

Comment: Hint: $\Pr(A\mid B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}$.

Comment: Yes I know that is the formula for conditional probability but I am confused on how to proceed. I figured out that k = 6 and calculated the CDF where F(X) = 6(x^2/2 -x^3/3)

Comment: It is a good thing to find $k$ even though we don't need it for the answer. We have $\Pr(B)=\int_0^{0.8} 6x(1-x)\,dx$ and $\Pr(A\cap B)=\int_0^{0.4} 6x(1-x)\,dx$. Now calculate.

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}\Pr(X\leq 0.4\mid X\leq 0.8)
& =\dfrac{\Pr(X\leq 0.4 \cap X\leq 0.8)}{\Pr(X\leq 0.8)}
\\[1ex] & =\dfrac{\int_0^{0.4}kx(1-x)\operatorname dx}{\int_0^{0.8}kx(1-x)\operatorname dx}
\\[1ex] & =\dfrac{\int_0^{0.4}x-x^2\operatorname dx}{\int_0^{0.8}x-x^2\operatorname dx}
\\[1ex] &=\dfrac{{[\tfrac{x^2}{2}-\tfrac{x^3}{3}]}_0^{0.4}}{{[\tfrac{x^2}{2}-\tfrac{x^3}{3}]}_0^{0.8}}
\\[1ex] & =\frac{\tfrac{22}{375}}{\tfrac{56}{375}}
\\[1ex] & =\tfrac{11}{28}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks Graham. Good catch of my typos.